# CodeIgniter forfeit default views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm in the process of creating a quick "hack". I've never used CodeIgniter before, so what i'm asking is probably pretty basic stuff.

I have a controller that outputs some JSON data. However, with the setup i'm working with comes a default view which creates some html to the end of the file and so, my JSON parser throws a fit. Is there a way to disable views altogether as i really don't need a template file of any kind for this purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable views"? you shouldn't output directly in controllers..Anyway, just avoid calling a view? What's your real problem here?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yes, i agree, hence the "hack" comment. But, in addition, i don't understand why anyone would create a JSON file through a template file. That's just clunky as sh*t if you ask me. The real problem: there's a default view that loads automagically. And the question: how to disable that?

Comment: What? there's no default view whatsoever, and views are not loaded "automagically"... (there's default controller specified in configs, yes, but can be changed, and if you don't load any view there, no views are displayed). Are we talking about the same codeigniter framework?

Comment: @DamienPirsy All i know is that at the end of my file i get a bunch of html. Looks like it's a .tpl file at the root of the views directory. It's definitely CodeIgniter, don't reckon there's many versions of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an `exit()` at the end of action to do this.

```
exit();
```

Comment: Wow, that's hacky :) Well, i guess i got what i asked for.

Comment: I appreciate your help and the solution suites me just fine. I'm just waiting if someone would have a less hacky solution that would better serve other people who might be looking into the same thing.

Comment: It's not a 'hacky' solution - using `exit;` is a common way to ensure output and parsing stops at a desired point. Also in CI.

Comment: Ok. Sure seems hacky though :)